# Error connecting to MySQL from Node-JS server

Tags: mysql, node.js, ubuntu-server

I am learning to develop server on node-js and have developed a basic get function which retrieves data from MySQL DB hosted on a ubuntu server at digitalocean.

Here's my code:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const mysql = require('mysql')
const Client = require('ssh2').Client;
const ssh = new Client();

const db = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
ssh.on('ready', function() {
  ssh.forwardOut(
    // source address, this can usually be any valid address
    'localhost',
    // source port, this can be any valid port number
    3333,
    // destination address (localhost here refers to the SSH server)
    'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
    // destination port
    22,
    function (err, stream) {
      if (err) throw err; // SSH error: can also send error in promise ex. 
reject(err)
      // use `sql` connection as usual
         connection = mysql.createConnection({
          host     : '127.0.0.1',
          user     : 'user',
          password : 'pass', 
          database: 'mysql',
          stream: stream
        });

        // send connection back in variable depending on success or not
    connection.connect(function(err){
        if (!err) {
            resolve(connection)
        } else {
            reject(err)
        }
    });
  });
}).connect({
  host: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', //IP address where DB is hosted
  port: 22,               //Port refering to the IP 
  username: 'user',       //username to loginto the host  
  password: 'pass'  //password to log into host
});
});

//Retrieve route
app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
//console.log("Fetching user with id: " + req.params.id)

const queryString = "SELECT * FROM user"

connection.query(queryString, (err, rows, fields) => {

if(err){
    console.log("Failed to query " + err)
    res.sendStatus(500)
    return
}
console.log("Fetch Succesful")
res.json(rows)
})
})


app.listen(3000, () => {
console.log("Server is up and listerning on port 3000")
})
```

When I run this code on my local machine it is able to connect to external DB and fetch the data. I have created another server at digitalocean and hosted the same code. However upon running it I get error at connection stating: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306`
I tried various solutions available on the platform but could not suceed.

I have written the code accoring to the documentation but still clueless what's causing the error.

Thank You.

Comment: Is you mysql server running?

Comment: Yes it is running. I am able to fetch data from the DB with same code from my local machine (Windows).

Comment: Is the server side mysql instance listen on localhost or on the external IP Adress?

Comment: MySql instance is on external IP address.

Comment: So you have to use this not localhost

Comment: You mean the host under `mysql.createConnection` ?

Comment: yes that is what i mean

Comment: I still get the same error when I replace localhost with the host IP address.